# How to enable developer option in IOS 10.0.1 [GM]?

Tags: ios, ipad, testing, ios10

I am trying to get developer option in IOS 10.0.1 [beta version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4s4K.png) but it is showing the black screen in my Ipad !

Can anyone help regarding it ?

Comment: Can you please attach the screenshot(s) with it indicating from where you are trying to get developer option and also the black screen when you click on some link ?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/i4s4K.png  Please check this link